# How can I display values of an array in an inline command without the "," in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, onclick

I have a JavaScript where I created the 'z' array, which is the current hour and minute. I would like to print 'z' onclick, but not in an array format.

If the current time is 2:18, the output of the code below is:
2,18. What I would like is 2:18.

Thank you for your consideration and answer!

```
<script>
  var today = new Date();  
  h = today.getHours();  
  m = today.getMinutes();  
  z = [h,m];  
</script>  

<button onclick="document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML=z">time</button>
<p id="demo"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

While there are many better ways to do this, you can use:
 `z.join(':')`

I would check out http://momentjs.com/

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML=z[0]+':'+z[1];
```

Answer (score 0):

Change `z` to:

```
z = h + ":" + m;
```

It will display as expected.